# Closing questions on mobile theme also shows me flag counts

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

When I'm using the Stack Exchange mobile view (specifically on my iPhone), after voting to close a question I am also shown the flag count. If I refresh the page afterwards, the flag count disappears and I don't think there is (or should be) any way that a non-moderator should see this.

Take for example [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/303879/wireless-works-for-one-laptop-not-the-other). This is what I see before my close vote:

[image: Before close]

Additionally, the close vote dialog doesn't make it immediately obvious like the desktop version how the close votes are distributed, but this is a lesser issue:

[image: During close]

After the close dialog is gone, I get the "x votes remaining" message, and I am also shown the flag count, which I don't think I should be able to see.

[image: After close, with flag count]

Comment: You don't really see the flag count. It's actually the number of close votes. The Javascript improperly replaces the count at the *flag* label instead of the *close* label. This is probably because earlier, there was no separate *close* link on the mobile interface.

Comment: I have also been encountering this bug on the Windows Phone 7 when using the mobile site.

Comment: That is true: The mobile version of the theme didn't have a link to vote to close questions, before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an error in shared JavaScript between main and mobile once the flag link was separate on mobile (it wasn't originally), it'll be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

As slhck already said, that is not the number of flags: It's the number of closing votes that, instead of being reported to the right of "close" is shown to the right of "flag." This doesn't mean there is just a closing vote, and three flags for that question. Three is the number of closing votes for that question: the one that there was before you voted to close, yours, and the vote from another user who voted while you were voting. That is the reason the dialog box says, "This question still needs 2 vote(s) from other users to close."

If you refresh the page, the number of closing votes should be shown correctly.