# Voting to close on Stack Overflow mobile shows flag window (too)

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

On Stack Overflow mobile, whenever I vote to close a question, first the flag window pops up and then the close window. Now I've also had cases when only the flag window popped up and no close window.

It seems like a weird behavior; maybe someone will be able to shed light on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next deploy.

It was a side effect of how the close dialog is loaded on mobile.  First we load the flag dialog (which itself "contains" the close dialog), so you'd see it for second.  This was exacerbated by slow mobile connections.

Comment: While you're at it, this is a related issue: [Closing questions on mobile theme also shows me flag counts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/closing-questions-on-mobile-theme-also-shows-me-flag-counts)