# Updated vote count is misplaced after vote to close on iPhone

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing questions on mobile theme also shows me flag counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/closing-questions-on-mobile-theme-also-shows-me-flag-counts)

After voting to close a question using the mobile version of SO, the new close-vote count gets appended on the wrong item (on `flag` instead of `close`). This is illustrated by the before-and-after screenshots below.

[image: screenshot of question before and after vote to close]

The same thing happens on questions that already have existing votes. For example, starting with the following state:

```
edit  close(3)   flag
```

After casting a close vote, this happens:

```
edit  close(3)   flag(4)
```