# Voting to close through comment editing?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, mobile-web, comment-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing questions on mobile theme also shows me flag counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/closing-questions-on-mobile-theme-also-shows-me-flag-counts)

Whenever I edit a comment on the mobile site, the "Submit" button changes to "Vote to Close" (and I think I saw it say "Flag Question" once).

Bug? New feature? Unicorns?

Comment: [Ponies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479), not Unicorns.  ;-)

Comment: @jadarnel27 But Unicorns are the magically weaponized form of a pony, so they must be responsible too.  ;-)