# I see question's flag count on mobile version, but I shouldn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, moderator-abilities, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing questions on mobile theme also shows me flag counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/closing-questions-on-mobile-theme-also-shows-me-flag-counts)

Being under 10k on SO, I don't have access to moderator tools. However, on questions that have been flagged, I can see a count next to the flag link, which I believe is the count of flags raised for the question:

[image]

This never happen on full site, so I believe there's a bug in the mobile site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/closing-questions-on-mobile-theme-also-shows-me-flag-counts